# Laravel using where on eager loaded relationship

Tags: laravel, orm, eager-loading

Hi I have the following code to retrieve all posts along with their comments (1 to many relationship)

```
$posts = Post::with('comments')->get();
```

Now it works great but my problem is let say I want to do a search on the post title or comment content if given an optional parameter. Something like:

```
$posts = Post::with('comments');

if (Request::has('query')) {
    $posts = $posts->where('content', 'LIKE', '%' . Request::get('query'))->orwhere('title', 'LIKE', '%' . Request::get('query'));
}

$posts = $posts->get();
```

Now this doesn't work as 'content' column only exists on the comments table. Is there any way do use the where condition on the eager loaded comments relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`orWhereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) and [`orWhere()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses):

```
$posts = Post::with('comments');

if (request()->has('query')) {
    $posts = $posts->orWhereHas('comments', function($q) {
        $q->where('content', 'like', '%'.request('query'));
    })->orWhere('title', 'like', '%'.request('query'));
}

$posts = $posts->get();
```

Test it. If you'll want to change behavior, you can use `whereHas()` and/or `where()` inside `if()` construction.

Answer (score 0):

Use `whereHas()` when building your query, an example from the docs:

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function ($query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
})->get();
```

[Docs link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Comment: What if I have a where condition on the original Post table too as shown in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

```
if (request()->has('query')) {
    $posts = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . Request::get('query'))->with(['comments' => function ($query) {
        $query->orWhere('content', 'LIKE', '%' . Request::get('query'));
    }]);
} else {
    $posts = Post::with('comments');
}

$posts = $posts->get();
```

And i thought @Alexey Mezenin's answer was incorrect, the result would be all posts with comments.